# Feed only showing 1 result?

Tags: rss, feed

Any ideas? It seems my feed is only showing one post, although I made several today.

http://www.alpinezone.com/category/news-and-featured-articles/feed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time I went to it I got this error "XML parsing failed: syntax error (Line: 77, Character: 8)"

Check the feed validator for more help http://validator.w3.org/appc/

Comment: That was it ... I had Yoast SEO installed and I included an advertisement banner tag insert and it was stopping the feed at that point. This looks like it fixed it. Thanks!